# Which rule engine is used in TFS for alerts?

Tags: tfs, alerts

When you create an alert in TFS a new record in tbl_EventSubscription appears.
It looks like this:

```
"SourceWorkItem/TeamProject" = 'ProjectName' 
AND "ChangedBy" <> '@@MyDisplayName@@' 
AND ("RequestedBy" = '@@MyDisplayName@@' 
OR "Reviewers[count(Reviewer[@Name = '@@MyDisplayName@@']) > 0]" <> null)
```

Which rule engine do they use to create/parse these rules? WF, Drools, own?

Answer (score 0):

The rule engine is internal to TFS although the build system uses windows workflow for build process management.